# 'LList::operator=': must return a value

Tags: c++, return, return-value, operator-keyword

I am working on an assignment where I create test code to show the implementation of a linked list class in C++. Mostly all the code provided is given from a book other than what I have written for my main function and a few edited lines to add a tail instance. The only error that is showing up right now when I compile is this:

```
    'LList::operator=' : must return a value
```

I am unsure as to why this error is being produced or how to fix it because it refers to a block of code that was given by the book. That block of code is:

```
    LList& LList::operator=(const LList& source)
    {
        dealloc();
        copy(source);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Just in case; here is the rest of the code from my source file.

```
// LList.cpp
#include "LList.h"
#include <iostream>

LList::LList()
{
    head_ = NULL;
    tail_ = NULL;
    size_ = 0;
}

ListNode* LList::_find(size_t position)
{
    ListNode *node = head_;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i<position; i++) {
        node = node->link_;
    }
    return node;
}

ItemType LList::_delete(size_t position)
{
    ListNode *node, *dnode;
    ItemType item;

    if (position == 0) {
        dnode = head_;
        head_ = head_->link_;
        item = dnode->item_;
        delete dnode;
    }
    if (position == size_) {
        dnode = tail_;
        node = _find(position - 1);
        node->link_ = NULL;
        tail_ = node;
        item = dnode->item_;
        delete dnode;
    }
    else {
        node = _find(position - 1);
        if (node != NULL) {
            dnode = node->link_;
            node->link_ = dnode->link_;
            item = dnode->item_;
            delete dnode;
        }
    }
    size_ -= 1;
    return item;
}

void LList::append(ItemType x)
{
    ListNode *node, *newNode = new ListNode(x);

    if (head_ != NULL) {
        node = _find(size_ - 1);
        node->link_ = newNode;
        tail_ = newNode;
    }
    else {
        head_ = newNode;
        tail_ = head_;
    }
    size_ += 1;
}

void LList::insert(size_t i, ItemType x)
{
    ListNode *node;

    if (i == 0) {
        head_ = new ListNode(x, head_);
        tail_ = head_;
    }
    else if (i == size_) {
        tail_ = new ListNode(x, tail_);
    }
    else {
        node = _find(i - 1);
        node->link_ = new ListNode(x, node->link_);
    }
    size_ += 1;
}

void LList::printlist()
{
    ListNode *temp = head_;

    while (temp) {
        std::cout << temp->item_ << std::endl;
        temp = temp->link_;
    }
}


ItemType LList::pop(int i)
{
    if (i == -1) {
        i = size_ - 1;
    }
    return _delete(i);
}

ItemType& LList::operator[](size_t position)
{
    ListNode *node;

    node = _find(position);
    return node->item_;
}

LList::LList(const LList& source)
{
    copy(source);
}

void LList::copy(const LList &source)
{
    ListNode *snode, *node;

    snode = source.head_;
    if (snode) {
        node = head_ = new ListNode(snode->item_);
        snode = snode->link_;

        while (snode) {
            node->link_ = new ListNode(snode->item_);
            node = node->link_;
            snode = snode->link_;
        }
    }
    size_ = source.size_;
}

LList& LList::operator=(const LList& source)
{
    dealloc();
    copy(source);
}

LList::~LList()
{
    dealloc();
}

void LList::dealloc()
{
    ListNode *node, *dnode;

    node = head_;
    while (node) {
        dnode = node;
        node = node->link_;
        delete dnode;
    }



}

int main()
{
    LList mylist;

    mylist.append(6);
    mylist.append(3);
    mylist.append(1);
    mylist.printlist();
    mylist.insert(2, 4);
    mylist.printlist();
    mylist.pop(1);
    mylist.printlist();
    mylist.size();
}
```

Comment: You need to get a different book. This code is terrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have this code:

```
LList& LList::operator=(const LList& source)
{
    dealloc();
    copy(source);
}
```

Change it to this:

```
LList& LList::operator=(const LList& source)
{
    dealloc();
    copy(source);
    return *this; // Note the addition of this return statement.
}
```

Explanation:

Here, you're overriding the `=` operator on LList, and in C++, operator overrides must return a value. At least in the case of `operator=`, you will most often want to just return the object itself.

Comment: On a side note, is "LList&" and "return *this"   a standard type and return combination?  Why this way, with reference type and *this return?